# DOM doesn't load in time when using angular cache

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, dom

I'm using a cache to store data fetched from an API, then using that data to make a chart in a `div` on my Angular app.

I think the cache returns the data faster than the DOM loads, because when I print `console.log(document.getElementByID(div_name)`, it prints `null`. The same line prints the right element when the data is fetched from the back-end.

Is there anyway I can make my function wait till the DOM is loaded to query the cache?

Comment: Can you share some more Info Or some code sample

Comment: Can't expose the API. It's literally just an `$http.get` request that gets cached. The `html` is 3 divs that are used to draw a chart on. When the request is sent to the API, it takes 3-4 seconds, then the `divs` are available. When getting the data from the cache, it's basically instant, and the `divs` are unavailable, so the page doesn't load completely. I think @JoelCDoyle's suggested post may work.